# use "this" in a function passed to eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hello people I was refactoring some code and couldn't figure a way to reuse the 'this':

a/ Code I have

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function (event){
  
   if( this.nextSibling.classList.contains('expanded') ){
       event.target.closest('.hello').getElementsByClassName('expanded')[0].classList.remove('expanded')
   }
});
```

b/ I want to move the function to another file and export it as:

```
export function doStuff(){ 
       if( this.nextSibling.classList.contains('expanded') ){
           event.target.closest('.hello').getElementsByClassName('expanded')[0].classList.remove('expanded')
       }
 }
```

and use it like:

```
import {doStuff} from 'somePath'
    
someElement.addEventListener('click', doStuff)
```

but 'this' is undefined.. how do I bind it?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter in the function. Your this is locally scoped to the file you are currently on so you have to give it as a reference to wherever you call your function from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `this` as parameter to function (and also decouple from `event` too):

```js
someElement.addEventListener('click', function (event){
   doStuff(this, event.target);
});

export function doStuff(element, target){ 
       if(element.nextSibling.classList.contains('expanded') ){
           target.closest('.hello').getElementsByClassName('expanded')[0].classList.remove('expanded')
       }
 }
```

Comment: turns out my code actually works fine.. no idea why I had a problem.. but your solution is also valid!